# linux device driver - ADS1292R problem in reading chip id on spi

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module, spi, ioctl

I am novice to Linux device driver and writing driver module for TI-ADS1292R chip. This driver is loading without any error, creates character device entry in */dev* directory. I am also able to transfer data on SPI bus (verified it on logic analyzer and DSO).

There are two problems here.
(1) in logic analyzer it shows that chip is responding with correct chip id (0x73) on read id command, but in my driver I am getting incorrect value (0x80). Why this is happening and where the problem is?

(2) As far as I understood, my driver should automatically loaded if I have configured it through *defconfig* file, which is not happening in my case. Right now, I am loading it as a built-in module with `obj-y` option.

My code has following snippets through which I am trying to read the chip id.

```c
static int ads_send_byte(struct ads1292_chip *dev, int data)
{
    int status;
    struct spi_message msg = { };
    struct spi_transfer transfer = { };

    dev->tx_buff[0] = data;
    transfer.tx_buf = dev->tx_buff;
    transfer.rx_buf = dev->rx_buff;
    transfer.len = 1;
    transfer.speed_hz = SPI_BUS_SPEED;

    spi_message_init(&msg);
    spi_message_add_tail(&transfer, &msg);
    status = spi_sync(dev->spi, &msg);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "ecg: %s (%#x) %d\n", __func__, data, status);
    return status;
};

static int ads_send_RREG(struct ads1292_chip *dev, char __user * buf, u8 reg, u8 size)
{
    struct spi_message msg = { };
    struct spi_transfer transfer = { };
    int ret;

    dev->tx_buff[0] = ADS1292_RREG | reg;
    dev->tx_buff[1] = size - 1;             // datasheet: no of regs - 1
    memset(dev->rx_buff, 0, size);
    memset(dev->tx_buff + 2, 0, size);
    transfer.speed_hz = SPI_BUS_SPEED;
    transfer.tx_buf = dev->tx_buff;
    transfer.rx_buf = dev->rx_buff;
    transfer.len = size + 2;            // 2 is for command tx
    transfer.delay_usecs = 40;          // datasheet: 4 clocks after each message
    transfer.cs_change = 1;             // Always toggle CS line after transfer
    spi_message_init(&msg);
    spi_message_add_tail(&transfer, &msg);
    ret = spi_sync(dev->spi, &msg);

    //printk(KERN_DEBUG "ecg: %s %x\n", __func__, dev->rx_buff[0]);
    if (unlikely(ret))
        return ret;

    ret = copy_to_user(buf, dev->rx_buff, size);
    return ret;
}

static int ads_cdev_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    struct ads1292_dev *ads = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct ads1292_dev, dev);
    char buff[1];

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "ecg: %s\n", __func__);

    filp->private_data = ads;
    gpio_set_value_cansleep(ads1292_gpio_start.gpio, 0);

    ads_send_byte(&ads->chip, ADS1292_RESET);
    mdelay(1);
    ads_send_byte(&ads->chip, ADS1292_SDATAC);
    mdelay(10);

    ads_send_RREG(&ads->chip, buff, ADS1292_ID, 1);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "ecg: ID - %x\n", buff[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `copy_to_user()` (besides being wrongly handled in error case) doesn't belong to `->open()` callback. It's rather `->read()` or so.

Comment: How can I handle it in a correct way? I used memcpy() instead of copy_to_user() as it was giving constant value of 0x80 each time even though I m trying to copy static value there.

Comment: yes, it is showing random values. Sometimes 0xD0, sometimes 0xC0.